# Executing command from specific line from a file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm making a script that execute specific line from a file containing my most used long commands each line (some kinda bookmarks for long commands).

For example I have a file that the first line is:

```
eog -f ~/Pictures/Cheatsheet\ Infographic/blender-3d-cheatsheet.png
```

But when I execute it with:

```
$(sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file)
```

It opens image viewer but said "the given location contains no image." And if I call:

```
"$(sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file)"
```

It said "zsh: no such file or dir..."

Although it works well if I use `eval` like this:

```
eval $(sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file)
```

But I  read somewhere that I should avoid using `eval` since the disaster brought with it (I don't understand it actually).

My quests is:

1. What is it with behavior I wrote above?
2. Any solutions to execute specific line from a file as a command other than using `eval`?

Many thanks to you guys...

---

**Edit:** Tried `exec`, same as I just stated above: It opens image viewer but said "the given location contains no image." But if I close that image viewer, terminal is closed as well.

Comment: It's better to ask one question per post, as people not knowing all 3 answers are much less likely to answer here.

Comment: Use aliases, or even better, functions.

Comment: @choroba ops you're right, sorry, let me edit it first... about using aliases, I've already have had too much aliases and functionss...

Comment: Have you tried `exec` instead of `eval`?

Comment: @Broman whoa, just heard about `exec`, lemme try it first

Comment: Define functions, source the file, then call functions.

Comment: `eval` is bad for *untrusted* input; presumably, you trust your input, although you might unintentionally add a command that will have side effects (like expanding a parameter you forgot to set) that makes `eval` unsuitable in this case. `exec` is completely different and *not* what you want here.

Comment: @chepner yeah just tried `exec`, it's not what i desired indeed. oh, so problem with `eval` is just about trusting input, guess I'll stick with it. It's not like I'm putting `rm -rf` in my bookmarks.

Comment: @user312781 Yet. `eval` is not a convenience; it's a last resort. Don't go looking  for ways to use it instead of safer alternatives.

Comment: Your question is tagged `bash` whereas you are obviously using `zsh`, according to the error message.

Comment: @xhienne writing script with shebang directed to bash actually. Using zero based index in array too.

Comment: @chepner While I completely agree with your "eval is bad for untrusted input", I do not agree with you advice of using a safer alternative, for the sole reason that there is no safer alternative. OP's intent is to evaluate and execute the Nth line in the file and, whatever the mean to execute it, if there is an unintentional side-effect to it, then it will be triggered, and it's not eval's fault, it's just a consequence of evaluating and executing the given line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your file contains valid commands, you can use any of those commands, depending on your needs:

- `source <(sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file)`
- `eval "$(sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file)"`
- `sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file | bash`

By "valid" I mean properly escaped if I judge by your sample line. That means that if one line contains something like `eog -f /tmp/$file` I assume the `$` is intentionally not escaped, is not part of the actual file name, and `$file` should be substituted with the content of the `file` variable.

So, using `eval` is safe but, on the other hand, you may have issues with the `$(sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file)` part if you don't quote it properly (and you didn't). Example:

```
$ line='printf "%s\n" "Four spaces = <    >"'

$ eval "$line"           # Correct output
Four spaces = <    >

$ eval $line             # Incorrect output
Four spaces = < >

$ IFS=%; eval $line      # Incorrect output
 s
```

As for your other attempts:

- `$(sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file)` has the same issues: each whitespace-delimited part of your line is turned into a single word, therefore `eog` is called with `~/Pictures/Cheatsheet\` and `Infographic/blender-3d-cheatsheet.png` as second and third parameters respectively. Obviously, those two files don't exist.
- `"$(sed -n "1 p" /path/to/that/file)"` is one single word, i.e. the executable is the whole line, and it is not called with any parameter. Obviously the command does not exist.

Comment: Whooaaa thanks so muchh... It enlights me about the problem and you even give elegant solutions... that `source <` is new to me, and pipes to `bash`? Never thought about that...

Comment: @user312781 Just keep in mind that piping to `bash` creates a whole new environment and you will only inherit environment variables. That may be a good thing security-wise, though. As for `source`, it's not `source < ...` but `source <( ... )` (process substitution).